# Clang: How do I see where and why an ud2 instruction was generated?

Tags: c++, clang, undefined-behavior, instructions

In a really big project of mine, Clang seems to throw in `ud2` instructions at some function calls. However, even with `-Wall` it doesn't seem to tell me why. I am using coroutines quite heavily in that project, but the `ud2` instructions end up at non-coroutine function calls.

Thanks in advance
Tuxifan

Comment: They are inserted if reaching the instruction can only happen under UB situations, e.g., if optimizations are disabled, reaching the closing `}` of a non-`void` function or when UB is detected by UB sanitizer in trapping mode. In other words, whatever you are doing has undefined behavior.

Comment: Clang might also use them for padding that should not be executable, I am not sure at the moment, but if you reach that you also have UB.

Comment: But you can't expect Clang to reasonably diagnose all potential UB conditions with warnings at compile-time. That would produce an overwhelming amount of false positive warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang places `ud2` instruction at whatever place that would be undefined behavior to reach. Doing this is not feasible.